# Error: Assertion failed: result != null "Invalid modifier location: Control, 0"

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I get this Assertion failed error occasionally on Flutter-web.

> Paused on exception
>
> > Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-
> > sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart:339:16 result != null
> > "Invalid modifier location: Control, 0"

when I run through `if (event is RawKeyDownEvent)`

```
KeyEventResult _handleKeyPress(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {Do something}
    }
}
```

I'm  trying to handle keypress events on a  TextField. It doesn't happen all the time. I'm trying to figure out what could be causing it.